# URL Routing in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, routes, url-routing

I am working with angular 2.1.1. I use angular routing in my app. It's working fine. When I click on a menu then it routes correctly. But the problem is, when I type a URL in address bar instead of clicking on the menu then I get error message.

I think the problem is, when I type an URL and hit enter then the browser send a request to server. But the routing configuration is in the client. So the server response with an error message.

In angular 1 there was an # in URL which restrict the browser to send the request to the server. But in angular 2 there is no # in URL.

I can configure the server so that every URL redirect to the root URL. But that not the solution. I can't bookmark any URL.

How can I solve the problem???

Comment: We cannot understand like this. Can you add here you routing code?

Comment: You can use HTML5 routing no problem (and will want to if SEO is an issue) but you will have to make sure whatever you are using to serve the app is handling all child routes and redirecting them to the app page. So really it's a server side routing issue, you should ask another question specific to that.

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 also has **`#`** which is used with **[HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/HashLocationStrategy-class.html)** and it seems that you are using **[PathLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/PathLocationStrategy-class.html)**.

If you use PathLocationStrategy, make sure server is configured to serve the requested url response.

You can use **HashLocationStrategy(#)** in your app as follow,

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // ...<<<---here
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Further reading : - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html look for  **HashLocationStrategy**

Comment: If I want to use PathLocationStrategy then, is there any way to solve the problem??

Comment: Then make sure server is configured to serve the pages you want. server needs to be configured. For example, if you are using .net mvc5, make sure mvc5 routing is capable enough to serve the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `locationStrategy`.

The default settings is the `PathLocationStrategy`, but you can also use the `HashLocationStrategy`:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(yourRoutes, { useHash: true })
```

official docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#-hashlocationstrategy-